# Unexpected behavior in symbolic integration with GenerateConditions->False

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

Consider the following two symbolic integrations:

```
int[a_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[-t^2 + r^2 + r0^2 - 2 r*r0* z] LegendreP[a, z]
Table[Integrate[int[a, z], {z, -1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {t > 0 && r > 0 && r0 > 0}, 
  GenerateConditions -> True], {a, 0, 3}]
```

and

```
int[a_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[-t^2 + r^2 + r0^2 - 2 r*r0* z] LegendreP[a, z]
Table[Integrate[int[a, z], {z, -1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {t > 0 && r > 0 && r0 > 0}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False], {a, 0, 3}]
```

In the first I set `GenerateConditions->True` in the second `False`.

The second gives `0` for each `a`, while the first gives a long result which is (very!) different from `0` (and no conditions btw).

Why is it so? I am using version 10 for Windows

**Edit** This is the output of the first code:

> `{(HeavisideTheta[((r + r0 - t) (r + r0 + t))/(r r0)] ((r + r0 -
>   t) (r + r0 + t) - ((r - r0)^2 - 
>          t^2) HeavisideTheta[((r - r0)^2 - t^2)/(r r0)]))/(2 r r0), -(((r - r0 - t) (r + r0 - t) (r - r0 + t) (r + r0 + 
>        t) HeavisideTheta[((r + r0 - t) (r + r0 + t))/(
>       r r0)] (-1 + HeavisideTheta[((r - r0)^2 - t^2)/(r r0)]))/(8 r^2 r0^2)), -(((r - r0 - t) (r + r0 - t) (r - r0 + t) (r + r0 + 
>        t) (r^2 + r0^2 - 
>        t^2) HeavisideTheta[((r + r0 - t) (r + r0 + t))/(
>       r r0)] (-1 + HeavisideTheta[((r - r0)^2 - t^2)/(r r0)]))/(16 r^3 r0^3)), -(((r - r0 - t) (r + r0 - t) (r - r0 + t) (r + r0 + 
>        t) (5 r^4 + 2 r^2 (3 r0^2 - 5 t^2) + 
>        5 (r0^2 - t^2)^2) HeavisideTheta[((r + r0 - t) (r + r0 + t))/(
>       r r0)] (-1 + HeavisideTheta[((r - r0)^2 - t^2)/(r r0)]))/(128 r^4 r0^4))}`

Comment: What happens when you apply `FullSimplify[]` to the output of the first snippet?

Comment: It returns the input

Comment: Nothing in the "long result" changed at all?

Comment: no, nothing changes

Comment: Try putting your assumptions as the second argument of `FullSimplify[]`.

Comment: It returns the input again

Comment: @J.M.  `FullSimplify` accomplished nothing for me either in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers given in the question are correct, consistent with the documentation of `Integrate`.  To see this, determine the value of `z` for which `HeavisideTheta` changes in value from `1` to `0`.

```
z0 = z /. Solve[-t^2 + r^2 + r0^2 - 2 r*r0*z == 0, z][[1, 1]]
(* (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0) *)
```

which also can be written as `1 + ((r - r0)^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)`.  Then, labeling as `s` the general solution provided in the edit of the question,

```
FullSimplify[s, z0 < -1]
{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

According to the `Options>GenerateConditions` section of `Integrate`, setting `GenerateConditions -> False` will "Generate a result without conditions that is valid only for some values of parameters", which we see is indeed the case.  For completeness,

```
FullSimplify[s, z0 > 1]
(* {2, 0, 0, 0} *)

FullSimplify[s, -1 < z0 < 1]
(* {((r + r0 - t) (r + r0 + t))/(2 r r0), 
   ((r - r0 - t) (r + r0 - t) (r - r0 + t) (r + r0 + t))/(8 r^2 r0^2), 
   ((r - r0 - t) (r + r0 - t) (r - r0 + t) (r + r0 + t) (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2))/(16 r^3 r0^3), 
   ((r - r0 - t) (r + r0 - t) (r - r0 + t) (r + r0 + t) (5 r^4 + 2 r^2 (3 r0^2 - 5 t^2) 
       + 5 (r0^2 - t^2)^2))/(128 r^4 r0^4)} *)
```

An alternative way of looking at this problem is to rewrite `int` as

```
int[a_, z_] := HeavisideTheta[z0 - z] LegendreP[a, z]
```

Thus, for `z0 < -1` `int` is `0` throughout the range of integration, `{z, -1, 1}`, so `Integrate` must yield `0` for all integer `a`.  For `z0 > -1`, on the other hand, the integrals take the form,

```
Table[Integrate[LegendreP[a, z] , {z, -1, Min[1, z0]}, Assumptions -> z0 > -1], {a, 0, 3}]
(* {1 + Min[1, (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)], 
    -(1/2) + 1/2 Min[1, (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)]^2, 
    -(1/2) Min[1, (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)] + 1/2 Min[1, (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)]^3,
    1/8 - 3/4 Min[1, (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)]^2 + 
        5/8 Min[1, (r^2 + r0^2 - t^2)/(2 r r0)]^4} *)
```

equivalent to `s` for `z > -1`.